# Latex won't quick build?

Tags: texmaker

I am completely new to Latex and have immediately run into a problem.
I made this very simple document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

When I try to quick build it, Latex doesn't give me an error, it just gives me the spinning loading wheel. It doesn't matter how long I wait, it just doesn't quick build.

I feel like I must be missing something very obvious in some setting but can't find out what.  Any ideas? 
The editor I am using is texmaker.

Comment: Welcome! Could you tell us which distribution of TeX you installed and which OS you are on? TeXmaker is just an editor. On its own, it can't compile anything. It relies on you having a TeX distribution such as TeX Live installed so that it can call the commands required to compile your document.

Comment: Open a terminal (Mac/Linux) or command window (Windows) and go into the directory of the test file and run `pdflatex <file>`. Then you'll see what happens. However, most of the editors also allow to see this output in the bottom of the main window.